# How do I fix #1062 error received while importing EE database to localhost from remote server

Tags: database, mysql, import, localhost

I am trying to import a MySQL database into the localhost database that was exported from the remote database and I am receiving a #1062 error (which is weirdly in French!):

`#1062 - Duplicata du champ '1' pour la clef 'PRIMARY'`

Google translate: `# 1062 - Duplicate field '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

The code that it highlights is as follows:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `exp_accessories`
--

INSERT INTO `exp_accessories` (`accessory_id`, `class`, `member_groups`, `controllers`, `accessory_version`) VALUES
(1, 'Expressionengine_info_acc', '1|5', 'content|members|admin_content|design|tools_communicate|homepage|addons_fieldtypes|content_files|admin_system|tools_data|addons|tools|tools_logs|tools_utilities|addons_accessories|content_files_modal|myaccount|addons_modules|addons_plugins|content_publish|content_edit|addons_extensions', '1.0'),
(2, 'Cartthrob_acc', '1|5', 'content|members|admin_content|design|tools_communicate|homepage|addons_fieldtypes|content_files|admin_system|tools_data|addons|tools|tools_logs|tools_utilities|addons_accessories|content_files_modal|myaccount|addons_modules|addons_plugins|content_publish|content_edit|addons_extensions', '1.0');
```

I am a novice with SQL and I can't see what it is on about. I can't see a duplicate in the primary key.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Many thanks

Gabe

Comment: do you have something in your localhost database in the same table? If yes - it is the reason of conflict. Possible you made dump w/o flag to DROP TABLE IF EXISTS. What do you use for dump?

Answer (score 0):

By default, mysqldump writes information as SQL statements to the standard output. You can save the output in a file: shell> mysqldump [arguments] > file_name !!!!!!!!!!